# On which table Subtotal of Item ordered values stored in magento 2 admin?

Tags: database, magento, magento2

On which table Subtotal of Item ordered values stored  in magento 2 admin?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `sales_order_item` database table and one of `row_total`, `base_row_total`, `row_total_incl_tax`, `base_row_total_incl_tax` fields.

I guess the subtotal is in `row_total_incl_tax` field.